# how to return last inserted (auto incremented) row id in HSQL?

Tags: sql, insert, hsqldb, auto-increment

i am working with HSQL database for testing purpose. i want standalone db file.
but now i am in trouble to get last inserted row id (auto-incremental - identity) in HSQL. how can i get id??

Comment: i got the solution

    CALL IDENTITY();

after insert row.... (but this will give last inserted row id)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It's pretty hard to write a query to perform this when you haven't given your table schema, but something like the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [TABLENAME] ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Comment: While this may work, it would be hard to imagine a more expensive way to get the generated identity.  Moreover, if rows are deleted from a table, there is no guarantee that the next identity value generated will always be the largest.

Comment: "there is no guarantee that the next identity value generated will always be the largest" - Regardless of the method used to obtain the id of the last row inserted you will always encounter this problem.

Comment: Prefer IDENTITY() (see ryanjustus' answer). Using the max ID of the table would return a wrong result if other concurrent transactions also insert data.

Answer (score 23):

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html

the last inserted value into an identity column for a connection is available using the function IDENTITY(), for example (where Id is the identity column):

```
INSERT INTO Test (Id, Name) VALUES (NULL,'Test');

CALL IDENTITY();
```

Comment: The link in this answer is out of date.  Info on Identity() can now be found in chapter 10 here: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_system_functions