# How to retrieve previously auto-generated PK ID value using JDBC and HSQLDB

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm working with JDBC and HSQLDB 2.2.9. What's the most efficient and accurate way to insert a new row into a DB and, subsequently, retain its `id` (PK set to autoincrement) value? The reason I need to do this is probably pretty obvious, but I'll illustrate with an example for discussion:

Say there's a `Customer` table that has a `PersonId` field with a FK constraint referring to a row from a `Person` table. I want to create a new `Customer`, but to do this I need to first create a new `Person` and use the new `Person.id` value to set `Customer.PersonId`.

I've seen four ways to approach this:

1. Insert the `Person` row setting the `id` field to `null`. HSQLDB generates the next `id` value automatically. Then perform a query on the `Person` table to get the `id` value just created and use it to create the new `Customer` row.

   This seems expensive just to retrieve a single integer value.
2. Get the next `id` value in the `Person` table and use it in the `INSERT` statement to set the `Person.id` value manually. Use the same `id` value to set `Customer.PersonId`. No subsequent read from the DB is needed.

   Inconsistencies may arise if an `id` value is obtained, but another connection performs an `INSERT` in the table before my `INSERT INTO Person...` statement is executed.
3. Execute the `INSERT` statement, as in option 1 above, setting `id=null` to allow auto-generation. Then use the `getGeneratedKeys` method to retrieve keys generated in last statement.

   I thought this sounded like a good option, but I couldn't get it to work. Here's a snippet of my code:

   ```
   // PreparedStatement prepared previously...
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
   ResultSet genKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
   int id;
   if (genKeys.next()) {
       id = genKeys.getInt(1);
   }
   // Finish up method...
   ```

   This code was returning an empty `ResultSet` for `genKeys`. Am I using the `getGeneratedKeys` method incorrectly? If I could get this to work, this might be the way to go.
4. Again, execute the `INSERT` statement allowing for auto-generated `id`. Then immediately execute `CALL IDENTITY()` to retrieve the last `id` value generated by the connection (as explained [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html#N104B3) and mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353405/how-to-return-last-inserted-auto-incremented-row-id-in-hsql) SO question).

   This also seems like a reasonable option, even though I must perform an additional `executeQuery`. On the positive side, I was actually able to get it to work with the following code:

   ```
   // INSERT statement executed here...
   statement = connection.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("CALL IDENTITY();");
   int id;
   if (rs.next()) id = rs.getInt(1);
   // Finish up method...
   ```

So, in summary, the first two options I'm not crazy about. The second two seem ok, but I could only get option 4 to work. Which option is preferred and why? If option 3 is the best, what am I doing wrong? Also, is there a better way that I haven't mentioned? I know words like 'better' can be subjective, but I'm working with a simple DB and want the most direct solution that doesn't open up the DB to possible inconsistencies and doesn't increase the transaction failure rate (due to trying to create a record with an `id` that already exists).

This seems like a basic question (and essential), but I couldn't find much guidance on the best way to do it. Thanks.

---

EDIT:
I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc/1915197#1915197) question that discusses my option 3. According to the accepted answer, it appears I was leaving out the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` parameter needed to enable that functionality. I didn't show the `prepareStatement` method in my code snippet, but I was using the single parameter version. I need to retry using the overloaded, two-parameter version.

There are also a few other SO questions which show up with that question that are closly related to my question. So, I guess mine could be considered a duplicate (not sure how I missed those other questions before). But I'd still like any guidance on whether one solution is considered better than the others. For now, if I get option 3 to work, I'll probably go with that.

Comment: To be honest, I don´t see why you won´t stick to your solution No1. Making a SELECT on the ID of the newly inserted row has the usual overhead of a query, but then again, all your other options do too.

Comment: I wouldn't be `SELECT`ing on `id`, but rather on a bunch of other fields that comprise another unique key. The `id` value would be what I'm looking for. But your comment about the "usual overhead of a query" still stands regardless of the details of the query. However, I wasn't sure of the overhead entailed in option 3. I thought that info would be left over from the previous statement execution. For option 4 I wasn't sure if executing a query of `CALL IDENTITY()` was any cheaper than a "regular" `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I don´t know if it is, either. Personally, I wouldn´t worry about just one query after an insert, but naturally I don´t know the specifics of your task.

Comment: I agree, and to be honest I'm not overly worried about performance. However, I'm still relatively new at this, and didn't want to hack in something that works before I investigated whether there were more elegant solutions readily available. No premature optimization, just a bit of due diligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much action here, so I'll go ahead and answer to bring closure to this question. After playing around with the different options, and after see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc/1915197#1915197) question, I was able to get my option 3 to work. Like I mentioned in the edit to my question, I'm going to use option 3. Option 4 also worked fine, but since the accepted answer to the linked question is given by a reputable source, I am sticking with that. I wish I'd have seen that question/answer before starting this one, I'd have saved some time!

Comment: Option 3 is the best because the generated key is returned when the INSERT statement completes, minimising the extra operations that other options require.

Comment: That's what I figured, and the main reason I went with that option. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you are willing to use an ORM, they will do all of the work for you. See [Sormula Identity Column](http://www.sormula.org/identity/) example.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on neizan's answer, but here's how I solved the same problem:

- The column looked like an ID column, but it wasn't defined as IDENTITY;
- As said above, you need to specify RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS.
- It looks like if you execute 2 INSERT in sequence, the second one won't return the generated keys. Use "CALL IDENTITY()" instead.

Example using HSQLDB 2.2.9:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
 ID INTEGER IDENTITY,
 NAME VARCHAR(30)
)
```

Then in Java:

```
PreparedStatement result = cnx.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(ID, NAME) VALUES(NULL, 'TOM');",
    RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int updated = result.executeUpdate();
if (updated == 1) {
    ResultSet generatedKeys = result.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        int key = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so annoying. I've been trying to solve my problem for a few days now and I just realized that I was getting the int of index 0. I forgot that ResultSets are 1-indexed as well...