# How should my INSERT INTO statement for GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY be?

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm trying to use GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY key for my record id's for my tables because a user needs to register themself and the user shouldn't be able to choose their own record id. So I decided to use GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY but I don't know how to write my INSERT statements.

This is my user table:

```
CREATE TABLE USER
(
   ID_USER INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
   USERNAME VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   FORENAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   SURNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   PASSWORD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   USER_TYPE INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(ID_USER),
   FOREIGN KEY (USER_TYPE) REFERENCES USER_TYPES(ID_TYPE)
);
```

and users will be allowed to register themselves.

[This](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Getting_Started_Guide/beta422/html/images/hsql-manager.png) is what im using for my database

Comment: It's ok to be new! Thank you for editing! :) Can you post some of your Java code that is interacting with your database as well? I'm trying to understand your comment below where you said you are using the UI to do the INSERT statements, but it seems like you want the ID from the INSERT to use in another INSERT elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When a table has a column GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY it means that you can insert with a value in that column if you want to but you don't *have* to. So then in your insert, you could instead write

```
INSERT INTO ARTIST (ORIGIN,ARTIST_NAME) VALUES ('USA','Nirvana');
```

For reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_identitycols.html

Edit after comment:

In the case where you need to retrieve the ID, @Mathias was correct that this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858499/how-to-retrieve-previously-auto-generated-pk-id-value-using-jdbc-and-hsqldb). A possible solution taken from this answer would be:

```
PreparedStatement result = cnx.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO ARTIST (ORIGIN,ARTIST_NAME) VALUES ('USA','Nirvana')",
    RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
int updated = result.executeUpdate();
if (updated == 1) {
    ResultSet generatedKeys = result.getGeneratedKeys();
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        int key = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
    }
}
```

where `key` has the ID that you need for your next query.

Comment: but i use this id as a foreign key in a song table??  INSERT INTO SONG (ID_SONG, SONG_CODE, SONG_TITLE,GENRE,AVAILABILITY,ID_ALBUM,ID_ARTIST) VALUES 
(‘1’,’S1’,’Come As You Are’,’Rock’,’Available’,’1’,’1’);

Comment: @pofuduktavsancik: then you need to obtain the generated value after inserting the song. Check out `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`

Comment: The link to the DB2 Z/OS manual is not helpful as this question is for [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name INSERT INTO ALBUM (RELEASED_COUNTRY,RELEASE_YEAR,ALBUM_NAME) VALUES (‘USA’,’2000’,’Nirvana Deluxe’); my HSQLDB statement should be like that and I need to generated key statement in java code,right?

Comment: @Ashley but im using HSQLDB's Driver Manager UI to INSERT statements

Comment: @pofuduktavsancik I'm confused - you are using the UI to run the insert statements but you want the ID of the resulting row to use in your Java code? Please update your original question with more detail!

Comment: @Ashley i updated, sorry im so new here and im so confused too :(

Comment: There is no need to check the update count. If the insert succeeded you **know** there is one row, and otherwise an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly different from the one already answered and needs a different answer.

The OP states: `user shouldn't be able to choose their own record id`. In that case the column definition should be `ID_USER INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` to disallow any user-supplied value.

The table name shouldn't be `USER` as this is a reserved word. Try `USERS` instead.

The insert statement shouldn't insert into the `ID_USER` column. Similar to the example in the other answer, it should list the columns that are being inserted. An example below:

```
 INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME, FORENAME, SURNAME, PASSWORD, USER_TYPE)
   VALUES ('JohnSmith','John', 'Smith', 'apasswrdx67', 3)
```

The OP wants to insert the generated value into another table using the GUI DatabaseManager. This is done by using the IDENTITY() function immediatly after inserting that row. For example,

```
 INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (X, Y, Z) VALUES (IDENTITY(), 'some value', 'other value')
```